# formula for $a_n$ where $a_{n+1}=4-a_n-\frac1{a_n}$ and $a_1=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

There's a sequence $a_{n+1}=4-a_n-\frac{1}{a_n}$ staring with $a_1=1$.

Is it possible to find a general formula for $a_n$?

Comment: I expect not.  You have a sequence of rational numbers converging to a root of $2x^2-4x+1=2(x-1)^2-1$ ( think, I need to do more analysis to verify) which has roots $1\pm \sqrt{2}$.  If there were a nice closed form, either there would be no irrational parts to it (in which case, how does it have an irrational limit) or else the irrational parts have to somehow cancel out in each term but somehow not in the limit.  I'm not saying it's impossible, but it seems unlikely that a formula exists in simple terms.

Comment: @Aaron The ratio $F_{n+1}/F_n$ converges to the irrational $\phi$, every term is rational, but there are clear explicit formulae for each term involving exactly the sort of 'canceling irrationals' you mention; this is in fact standard behavior for linear recurrence relations. This isn't a linear recurrence relation but there's no reason that similar behavior couldn't happen here.

Comment: treat $a_{n+1},a_n$ as $y,x$ respectively then you can rewrite it in the form of $y=4-x-\frac 1x\implies yx=4x-x^2-1\implies x={-x^2+4x-1\over-x+1-\frac1x}$

Comment: I just divided by y which can be defined in terms of x.

Comment: then that shall be $\frac{-x^2+4x-1}{-x+4-1/x}$?

Comment: yep just replaced the y with what it equals it's probably not fruitful with my luck but I thought I'd at least try.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but a few steps in a possibly-fruitful direction: first of all, let's remove the inhomogeneous term.  Set $a_n=2+b_n$; then we can write $(2+b_{n+1})=4-(2+b_n)-\frac1{2+b_n}$ $=2-b_n-\frac1{2+b_n}$, or in other words, $b_{n+1}=-b_n-\frac1{2+b_n}$.

Now, we write $b_n=\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ and equate numerators and denominators; this gives $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}=-\dfrac{x_n}{y_n}-\dfrac{y_n}{x_n+2y_n}$ $=-\dfrac{2x_ny_n+x_n^2+y_n^2}{y_n(x_n+2y_n)}$ $=-\dfrac{(x_n+y_n)^2}{y_n(x_n+2y_n)}$.  In other words, we can equate your original recurrence relation with the paired recurrences $x_{n+1}=-(x_n+y_n)^2, y_{n+1}=y_n(x_n+2y_n)$.  (Or alternately, since $x_n$ is manifestly negative, we can write $x_{n+1} = (y_n-x_n)^2, y_{n+1}=y_n(2y_n-x_n)$ and then $b_n=-\frac{x_n}{y_n}$.)

Unfortunately, from here the trail looks to peter out; we can show that each fraction is in reduced terms ($\gcd(x_n, y_n)=1$ implies that $\gcd(x_n+y_n, y_n)=1$ and then that $\gcd(x_n+y_n, x_n+2y_n)=1$, so $\gcd(x_n+y_n, y_n(x_n+2y_n))=1$) but the structure of the recurrence suggests that growth is super-exponential and such quadratic recurrences tend not to have 'nice' forms unless there's some explicit telescoping or other cancellation involved in the terms.